# Unable to access JSON element

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following code in Win API Controller to return an object containing a Menu object and a list of CourseOption objects.

```
public object GetCourseOption(int id) //Here id is Menu id
{
    IEnumerable<CourseOption> courseoptions = db.CourseOptions.Where(c => c.MenuId == id);
    Menu menu = db.Menus.Single(c => c.Id == id);
    if (courseoptions == null)
    {
         throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }

    var combine = new { Menu = menu, Options = courseoptions };
    return combine;
}
```

I can access Menu properties by using the following code in JavaScript

```
$.getJSON("/api/CourseOptionAPI/" + id, function (data) {
alert("In " + data.Menu.Name);
});
```

but unable to access CourseOption properties by the following code

```
alert("In " + data.Options[0].Name);
```

The controller method is returning Options as part of 'combine' object (i have checked it by using breakpoint).
'Menu' and 'CourseOption' are objects and 'Name' is one of their properties (in both of them) of type string.

Comment: How do you pass the data from asp to JavaScript? Please, give a full example of the JSON string you've build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Name` may be one of the properties, but it looks like if `c.MenuId == id` keeps failing, you're never going to respond with any useful data and data.Options[0] will be undefined.

Like @zerkms said, `console.log` your incoming data and check what is in the JSON received.

Comment: Got it. I have to access it in javascript as 'alert("In " + data.Menu.CourseOptions[0].Name);'. console.log helped. Thanks.